# Why am i getting segmentation fault error while accessing a second level pointer?? C language

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

The following code generates segmentation fault error at run time... just because i try to
use `p_list3` (a second level pointer) to print its contents or assign it something...
**Note:** notice the `printf(...)` differences in each code pieces...
***The full code is at the end.***

```c
struct node **p_list2 = NULL, **p_list3 = NULL;
    p_list = &list;

    while((*p_list)->next != NULL)  //Start [[WHILE1]]
    {
        p_list2 = &(*p_list)->next;
        while(*p_list2 != NULL)  //start [[WHILE2]]
        {
            printf("%s   %s   %u\n", (*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word, p_list3);
            p_list2 = &(*p_list2)->next;
        }  //End [[WHILE2]]
        p_list3 = p_list;
        p_list = &(*p_list)->next;
    }  //End [[WHILE1]]
```

While, neither this

```c
struct node **p_list2 = NULL, **p_list3 = NULL;
    p_list = &list;

    while((*p_list)->next != NULL)  //Start [[WHILE1]]
    {
        p_list2 = &(*p_list)->next;
        while(*p_list2 != NULL)  //start [[WHILE2]]
        {
            printf("%s   %s   \n", (*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word);
            p_list2 = &(*p_list2)->next;
        }  //End [[WHILE2]]
        p_list3 = p_list;
        p_list = &(*p_list)->next;
    }  //End [[WHILE1]]
```

nor this

```c
struct node **p_list2 = NULL, **p_list3 = NULL;
    p_list = &list;

    while((*p_list)->next != NULL)  //Start [[WHILE1]]
    {
        p_list2 = &(*p_list)->next;
        while(*p_list2 != NULL)  //start [[WHILE2]]
        {
            printf("%s   %s   %u\n", (*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word, p_list3);
            p_list2 = &(*p_list2)->next;
        }  //End [[WHILE2]]
        //p_list3 = p_list;
        p_list = &(*p_list)->next;
    }  //End [[WHILE1]]
```

generates no such error.. what is happening here???

**Full code**

```
/*
@@@@ PROGRAM NAME: knkcch17proj05.c
@@@@ FLAGS: -std=c99
@@@@ PROGRAM STATEMENT: 
Write a program that sorts a series of words 
entered by the user:

    Enter word: foo
    Enter word: bar
    Enter word: baz
    Enter word: quux
    Enter word:
    
    In sorted order: bar baz foo quux

Assume that each word is no more than 20 characters long. Stop reading when the 
user enters an empty word (i.e., presses Enter without entering a word). Store 
each word in a dynamically allocated string, using an array of pointers to keep 
track of the strings, as in the remind2.c program (Section 17.2). After all 
words have been read, sort the array (using any sorting technique) and then use 
a loop to print the words in sorted order. Hint: Use the read_line function to 
read each word, as in remind2.c.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  //strcpy()
#include <stdlib.h>  //malloc(), free(), NULL, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>  //isspace()
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct node
{
    char word[10];
    struct node *next;
} *list = NULL;
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int read_line(char str[], int n);
//------------------------START OF MAIN()--------------------------------------
int main(void)
{
    printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    printf("File: %s, C Version: %ld, Date: %s, Time: %s\n\n", __FILE__, __STDC_VERSION__, __DATE__, __TIME__);

    char *str;
    struct node **p_list = &list, *new_word;
    //Get words from user
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        //Allocate memory of size about struct node + 10 bytes
        if((new_word = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: malloc failed.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //Read word
        (read_line(str, 10));
        if(!strlen(str))  //If '\n' is detected without reading character.
            break;
        //Read word is stored to node.
        strcpy(new_word->word, str);
        new_word->next = NULL;

        //Load the node to list
        *p_list = new_word;
        p_list = &(*p_list)->next;
    }
    
    //Print words in the order they entered
    printf("\nIn Unsorted order: ");
    new_word = list;
    while(new_word)
    {
        printf("%s  ", new_word->word);
        new_word = new_word->next;
        
    }
    
    //Sorting
    struct node **p_list2 = NULL, **p_list3 = NULL;
    p_list = &list;

    while((*p_list)->next != NULL)  //Start [[WHILE1]]
    {
        p_list2 = &(*p_list)->next;
        while(*p_list2 != NULL)  //start [[WHILE2]]
        {
            printf("%u   %u   %u\n", p_list, p_list2, p_list3);
            printf("%s   %s   %u\n", (*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word, p_list3);
            #if 0
            if((strcmp((*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word)) == 1)  //Start [[IF1]]
            {
                printf("%s   %s\n", (*p_list)->word, (*p_list2)->word);
                if(p_list3 != NULL)
                    (*p_list3)->next = *p_list2;  //update previous node.
                (*p_list)->next = (*p_list2)->next;
                (*p_list2)->next = *p_list;

                struct node *temp = *p_list;
                *p_list = *p_list2;
                *p_list2 = temp;
                
            }  //End [[IF1]]
            #endif
            p_list2 = &(*p_list2)->next;
            
        }  //End [[WHILE2]]
        p_list3 = p_list;
        p_list = &(*p_list)->next;
    }  //End [[WHILE1]]
    
    printf("\nIn sorted order: ");
    new_word = list;
    while(list)
    {
        //print the word
        printf("%s  ", list->word);
        //prepare to free the allocated memory
        new_word = list;
        list = list->next;
        //free the memory.
        free(new_word);
    }
    

    printf("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------END OF MAIN()---------------------------------------
int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
  int ch, i = 0;

  //while (isspace(ch = getchar()))
    //;
  ch = getchar();
  while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    if (i < n)
      str[i++] = ch;
    ch = getchar();
  }
  str[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: We can only explain why the pointers aren't pointing at valid allocated memory if you show us how the pointers get their values *and how the memory is allocated*. Also, please keep in mind that just because there is no error, doesn't mean the code is correct. Undefined behaviour is allowed to do *literally anything*, including "it appears to work".

Comment: `p_list = &list;` is the likely culprit.

Comment: `p_list = &list;` isn't a culprit, because, the `p_list` can traverse through the linked list. And the `printf()` function proves it.

Comment: You seem to be using `**` just for the sake of it. Get rid of the useless second level of indirection. When that is fixed, single-step through the program to find the bug.

Comment: I do not understand your point @Lundin, i didn't use second level of indirection at any point in the program to access any data.... I am using second level of pointers just to make changes in the linked list directly..

Comment: You are doing it all over the place, making the code unreadable for no good reason. Just nuke anything with `**` in your code then adjust expressions accordingly.

Comment: The code header comment says "Assume that each word is no more than 20 characters long." but the `word` member of your `struct node` only has enough room for 9 characters plus a null terminator. Change its length to at least 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yaachaka I'm going to answer your question rather narrowly, just addressing the reason for the segmentation fault, and refrain from commenting on whether the program works.

The reason for your crash is that in the call to **read_line** you are passing an uninitialized value for str:

```
char *str;
struct node **p_list = &list, *new_word;
//Get words from user
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter word: ");
    //Allocate memory of size about struct node + 10 bytes
    if((new_word = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: malloc failed.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Read word
    (read_line(str, 10));
    if(!strlen(str))  //If '\n' is detected without reading character.
        break;
    //Read word is stored to node.
    strcpy(new_word->word, str);
    new_word->next = NULL;
```

This is a problem because **read_line** expects the first argument to point to somewhere that it can store the line being read.  Given that you already have an unused buffer (**new_word->word**), you can fix your crash by changing the above code to read directly into new_node->word:

```
struct node **p_list = &list, *new_word;
//Get words from user
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter word: ");
    //Allocate memory of size about struct node + 10 bytes
    if((new_word = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: malloc failed.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //Read word
    (read_line(new_word->word, 10));
    if(!strlen(new_word->word)) { //If '\n' is detected without reading character.
        free(new_word);
        break;
    }
    new_word->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are all that are needed.
`str` had no memory allocated, `char str[21];` will work.
`read_line()` needs to use `if (i < n - 1)` to make sure the terminating zero will be within the array boundary.
For simplicity, each new word is added to the beginning of the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node
{
    char word[21];
    struct node *next;
};

int read_line(char str[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    printf("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    printf("File: %s, C Version: %ld, Date: %s, Time: %s\n\n", __FILE__, __STDC_VERSION__, __DATE__, __TIME__);

    char str[21];
    struct node *p_list = NULL;
    struct node *new_word = NULL;
    //Get words from user
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        //Read word
        read_line ( str, 21);
        if ( ! strlen ( str)) {  //If '\n' is detected without reading character.
            break;
        }
        if ( ( new_word = malloc ( sizeof *new_word)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error: malloc failed.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //Read word is stored to node.
        strcpy ( new_word->word, str);

        //Load the node to beginning of list
        new_word->next = p_list;
        p_list = new_word;
    }

    //Print words in the reversed order they entered
    printf("\nIn Unsorted order: ");
    new_word = p_list;
    while ( new_word)
    {
        printf("%s  ", new_word->word);
        new_word = new_word->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Sorting
    struct node *p_list2 = p_list;
    struct node *p_list3 = p_list;
    struct node *sort = p_list;

    while ( sort->next != NULL)  //Start [[WHILE1]]
    {
        p_list2 = sort->next;
        while ( p_list2 != NULL)  //start [[WHILE2]]
        {
            printf("%s   %s   %p\n", sort->word, p_list2->word, (void *)p_list3);
            p_list2 = p_list2->next;

        }  //End [[WHILE2]]
        sort = sort->next;
        p_list3 = sort;
    }  //End [[WHILE1]]

    printf("\nIn sorted order: ");
    new_word = p_list;
    while( new_word)
    {
        printf("%s  ", new_word->word);
        new_word = new_word->next;
    }

    new_word = p_list;
    while( new_word) {
        p_list = new_word;
        new_word = p_list->next;
        //free the memory.
        free( p_list);
    }

    printf("\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n");
    return 0;
}
//-------------------------END OF MAIN()---------------------------------------
int read_line(char str[], int n)
{
    int ch, i = 0;

    while  ( ( ch = getchar ( )) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (i < n - 1) {// - 1 to provide for terminating zero
            str[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    str[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tim Boddy, @user3121023 and others who took time for responding... The solutions solved issue of *segmentation fault*. I couldn't identify my fault of allocation of memory for `char *str` because it stored the read string to the linked list....